# How to create two store views with different designs?

Tags: multistore, store-view, design, header, footer

I would like to create two store views. One store view that has no header and footer (I want to use this one for my mobile apps). Another store view that has header and footer (I want to use this store view for my existing e-commerce website).

Comment: are you useing same design package???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:First of all create module control file Module name as Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/. - See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.nuncYnVE.dpuf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step2: config.xml is app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/ and code is

### Edit: Change event to controller_action_layout_load_before

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
            </custommodule>
        </models>
    </global>
<frontend>
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers> 
            <myredirect>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>myremove</method>
            </myredirect>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_load_before>
 </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

and observer code is

```
   <?php
    class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer
    {
    public function myremove($observer)
        {
            try{
                $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if($storeCode=='mobilestorecode'){
                   $blockName = 'footer'; // Add yours
                    $update = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
                    $removeInstruction = "<remove name=\"$blockName\"/>";
                  $update->addUpdate($removeInstruction);
}

            }catch(Excpetion $e){
                Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1),'null','mage32173.log');
            }

            return;

        }
        }
```

Just use the extension:
modified code:

> Mage::helper('mobiledetect')->isMobile() ;

**edited:**

```
 public function myremove($observer)
    {
        try{
    if(Mage::helper('mobiledetect')->isMobile()){
               $blockName = 'footer'; // Add yours
                $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
                $removeInstruction = "<remove name=\"$blockName\"/>";
              $update->addUpdate($removeInstruction);
    }

        }catch(Excpetion $e){
            Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1),'null','mage32173.log');
        }

        return;

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Dear Amit Bera, it hides header and footer when I call the url www.example.com/?___store=mobile with my browser. When I call the url www.example.com/?___store=mobile with my browser, it also effects to other pcs and they cannot see header and footer already only if they call www.example.com.

Comment: For other website users, if they browse by www.example.com, I want them to see with header and footer. But once I run www.example.com/?___store=mobile with my browser, other website users cannot see header and footer already even when they run by www.example.com.

Comment: how have you  define current store is  mobile and default??

Comment: I just follow your code. I just change the statement from if($storeCode=='mobilestorecode') to if($storeCode=='mobile') as 'mobile' store is already existed in my magento. I didn't change any settings in admin panel as well. I just create module and follow your way. But header and footer are hidden in other people browsers once I run www.example.com/?___store=mobile with my browser.

Comment: then you need to track  current device is mobile or pc and put the code in the conditions....

Comment: Could you guide me the way whether current device is mobile or pc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my magento admin panel, default setting is 'All store views'. I did not change the setting to 'mobile'. I tried to change the setting from 'All store views' to 'mobile'. All my design layout gone. For your code you provided above, do I need to change the setting from 'All store views' to 'mobile'?

Comment: try to this extension to get device https://github.com/vkathirvel/Magento-Extension-MobileDetect

Comment: Thanks, Amit Bera! I will try. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi, Amit Bera, is it possible to do like this? if(mobile device) { if(mobile apps) { hide header and footer } else { don't hide header and footer } }. If I use MobileDetect, header and footer will be hidden for mobile browsers and mobile apps. I only want to hide for mobile apps. I do not want to hide for mobile browsers. Is there a way? Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit Bera. It works. Thank you so much. I have accepted your answer.